# Setting width of table cell in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, html-table, outlook-2013

I am trying to make a list items with table cells. It is different with different email clients.

**Outlook 2011 here, which is correct spacing**

[image]

**Outlook 2013 here, which is not correct spacing**
[image]

Here is the code I wrote.

```
<tr>
                                            <td class="dot" style="padding-top: 10px;" valign="top" width="20px">•</td>
                                            <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  font-size: 21px;  font-weight: 300;   line-height: 1.48; color: #474747;" valign="top" class="">Identify and target conquest customers by vehicle, FICO, payments remaining, and more</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dot" style="padding-top: 10px;" valign="top" width="20px">•</td>
                                            <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  font-size: 21px;  font-weight: 300;   line-height: 1.48; color: #474747;" valign="top" class="">Automatically market to pre-qualified customers coming in for service</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dot" style="padding-top: 10px;" valign="top" width="20px">•</td>
                                            <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  font-size: 21px;  font-weight: 300;   line-height: 1.48; color: #474747;" valign="top" class="">OEM Partnerships and Co-Op Eligibility</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dot" style="padding-top: 10px;" valign="top" width="20px">•</td>
                                            <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  font-size: 21px;  font-weight: 300;   line-height: 1.48; color: #474747;" valign="top" class="">Exclusive access to expiring lease data from Experian</td>
                                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set width of the cell inside "style"...

```
<td class="dot" style="padding-top: 10px; width:20px;" valign="top">•</td>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to give inside style instead of width for table cell?

Comment: I am speculating on how Outlook 2013 would render HTML, but I strongly believe it would try to render as HTML5. As you may know HTML5 doesn't support "width" attribute for "td" tag. As the common practice HTML content always has to be verified with e-mail clients you are targeting as of those clients would have limited capability for HTML tags and style support. Good article about it: [Working with Outlook HTMLBody – a guide for Office developers](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/02/23/outlook-htmlbody-guide/), not sure if it's up to date.